# How to test a Windows8 app on a surface

Tags: deployment, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How do I port a Windows8 app that I built onto a Surface?  I've built the app using Visual Studio and I can test it just fine on the desktop machine by just hitting F5.  How can I put it onto a Surface to test it without having to publish it to the Store? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This link explains how to test your app on a Surface using remote debugging: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/10/26/remote-debugging-windows-store-apps-on-surface-arm-devices.aspx

A quick summary:
1. Download the Remote Tools for Visual Studio 2012 (from [here](http://aka.ms/JenVS2012), under "Additional software" near the bottom) and install them on your Surface.  
2. Launch the Remote Debugger on your Surface and configure it.  Leave it running and "listening".
3. Go back to your dev machine and, in Visual Studio 2012, change the Run dropdown to "Remote Machine".  Run and select your device.

Comment: Hi Jennifer, as the content of this link is quite useful but may be updated / deleted / removed, I believe worth to migrate at least a briefing description of what's there.

Comment: Tiago, great point.  I've updated with a quick summary of the post.

Answer (score 3):

you need to install the [**Remote Tools**](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#remote-tools) and config the Visual Studio to debug on a remote machine. The rest is quite simple.

More details:
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx)
[here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/10/26/remote-debugging-windows-store-apps-on-surface-arm-devices.aspx)