# How can I test a phonegap application on a Windows surface device?

Tags: cordova, windows-phone, surface

I have an application that is being developed on Phonegap.  It needs to run on Android, Apple and Microsoft tablets.  For the Android and Apple tablets it was easy to run, I just needed to get the phonegap developer application, http://app.phonegap.com/.  Unfortunately the Windows version runs on the Windows Phone version of the OS, not Windows 8 itself which is what the surface is running.  Is there any way to test on this device using the Developer App?  Alternatively, is there a way to partition the device in a way that I have a Windows Phone partition that can run the app?

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap developer app does not support `windows` platform as its dependent plugin [phonegap-plugin-contentsync](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync) only supports `wp8`.

Theoretically you could rebuild [phonegap-app-developer](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-developer) for `windows` platform if you implement `windows` native code of the `phonegap-plugin-contentsync`.

You can also take a look on this question: [How to test a Windows8 app on a surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572178/how-to-test-a-windows8-app-on-a-surface)